# How do I use animationWithDuration and Chameleon Gradients?

Tags: ios, swift

```
    func fadeLightBar(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(fadeTime, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { [unowned self] () -> Void in
                //self.lightBar.backgroundColor = RandomFlatColor()
                self.lightBar.backgroundColor = GradientColor(UIGradientStyle.LeftToRight, self.lightBar.frame, [RandomFlatColor(), RandomFlatColor()])
            }) { (stuff Bool) -> Void in
        }
    }
```

I want to fade a UIView from color to color. But, I want the UIView to be gradient color.

Doing the standard color-to-color works great. However, when I do the gradient, there is no fading at all. It just changes abruptly every X seconds.

I'm using this framework to generate gradients: https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon#gradient-colors-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework works in its way, not simply change the color. I think it manipulate the layer by adding a `CAGradientLayer` on it. If so, it is impossible to animate adding a layer.

If you want to actualize the fading, you actually can do it yourself by adding a `CAGradientLayer` and animate its `alpha`